# Why is my textview not getting refreshed after retrieving a value from the Sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-edittext, refresh, textview

I am trying to do the following. I have an  `Edittext` , a `Button`  and a   `TextView`   in a class called  `myprofile  extends  Fragment`. I am doing the following.

I enter a number in the Edittext. On clicking the Button my number gets saved in a `Sqlite`  Database. I am retrieving my number from the database and setting in the textview.

The problem is as follows. As I do the above mentioned procedure my textview doesn't get refreshed and it remains blank till I go to some other activity and come back.  Can anyone tell me how can I refresh the textview ?  I have done the following coding but it doesn't help. Here `b`  is the button and `e2` is the textview.

```
       b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                e2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         details=db.mydetails();

                                String h=details.get("phno");
                                e2.setText(h);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Are you sure you get value  in `String h` ?

Comment: use log to ensure you are getting value in String h.

Comment: I put the log in onTextChanged but I guess it is not getting called

Comment: It´s only an assumption, but the TextChangeListener is called when the text is changed. So You can´t set the method to Change the text inside the listener. Just do that stuff only on button click

Answer (score 0):

try put notifyDataChange() on onTextChanged. I think.. :)